# ui-router lazy load state using url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to see if I can use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to delegate setting of state to my app's sub-components by implementing lazy loading of the states.  While I managed to get the lazy loading part to work using `$state.go` or equivalent, I can't get it to work using the URL.

For example, on launch my `app` will only setup the following 2 states: `view1` and `view2`.  When `view1` state is loaded, it then setup it's own children states of: `view1.profile` and `view1.interest`.  Take a look at this sample site from [Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcoslin/b59cfa9a9a44bde04f9f):

http://bl.ocks.org/marcoslin/raw/b59cfa9a9a44bde04f9f/

As you will see from the example above, `View1Profile` is not a valid link on launch, but if you click on it, it will load `view1` and then load `view1profile` with resulting url:

http://bl.ocks.org/marcoslin/raw/b59cfa9a9a44bde04f9f/#/view1/profile

However, if you click on the generated url above, the `app` reloads and no longer knows about `view1profile` and redirect you back to `home`.  Any recommendation on how I can address this?  More specifically, is there anyway I can get the url to trigger `$stateNotFound` event?

Perhaps the answer is in part of their cryptic documentation on [How to: Lazy load states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-lazy-load-states).  I wasn't able to figure out what they mean by:

- how to set the retry promise on the event
- how to define the unfoundState using stored provider and resolve the promise

Comment: Marcos, I will be publishing a few ui-router extras soon, including FutureStates, i.e. Lazy loaded states.  Right now, my github repos only has my parallel/sticky states implementation, but I plan on adding future states (including via AngularAMD) within the week. Http://GitHub.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras

Comment: @ChrisT perfect timing as I am making some enhancements in angularAMD as well.  If you need additional feature in angularAMD, open an issue.  I am adding a `angularAMD.config` that will help to create to set `$stateProvider` on demand.

Comment: Marcos, I've uploaded a preview release of ui-router-extras, version 0.0.1-preview.  I added it to bower, so you can grab it from there, or just snag it from my github repo.  I haven't yet added tests for ngload, because I need to figure out how to do async requirejs testing.  This is a preview, and as such there is a lot of code to reorganize and clean.  However, I think it may help you.  Go here: https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/blob/master/release/ct-ui-router-extras.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marcos,

See http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/future/index.html for integration of FutureState with AngularAMD.

See http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future/ for API and overview of the $futureStateProvider.